# HP EliteBook 840 G2 My laptop's left click (Trackpad) button isn't working it only works when I'm using touchpad simultaneously

Tags: windows, touchpad

HP EliteBook 840 G2 My laptop's left click (Trackpad) button isn't working it only works when I'm using touchpad simultaneously when pressing the keys. I'm running latest Windows 10 20H update. And Snapstic as my trackpad driver.